# QPlainTextEdit: à è é ì ò should be turned into "a' e' i'..." during they are typed

Tags: qt, key, qplaintextedit

I'm using QtCreator to code a simple text editor, but i would need that letters like "à è é ì ò" will be turned into "a' e' e' i' o'" as they are typed...
There is a way to do it?

Comment: How are you coding the simple text editor? What classes do you use?

Comment: I'm just using the QPlainTextEdit to edit some text, load or save it in a "format" which don't allow "à ò ì etc..." letters.
I Would like if the user could see the changes in real time, just when typing...

I have a function to load text that change "on the fly" these chars when load text:
        " line.replace(QString("à"), QString("a'"));
        line.replace(QString("è"), QString("e'"));
        ui->Text->appendPlainText(line); "
But i like to have something for the "real time" edit...

Comment: You'd have to filter the key events reaching the widget and limit the available alphabet that way.

Comment: I don't want to just "limit" the alphabet... i want to change the chars in realtime... addind 2 chars instead one pressed...

Comment: An event filter can do that as well.